# What to prefer: abstract class or interface when using services (e.g. app42, facebook, google+ etc.) and IoC

Tags: c#, interface, inversion-of-control, abstract-class, solid-principles

Recently I discovered DI for myself and SOLID principles so now I started my project and it often uses social services so I want to follow that principles to create a good architecture.

Let's say, I have a login page where the user can login with social services credentials, or using login and password registered earlier. According to DI I must have an abstraction which 'promises' the needed functionality but for me the problem is that App42 login method requires login and password but some other service (e.g. facebook) don't or may not. I could possibly create separate interface for App42 and facebook but this is not the case because the more services I would like to use in future (e.g. Twitter) the more interfaces I would have and the links to them in login page would grow.

`public interface ICredentialsAuthenticatable
    {
        void Login(string username, string password, Action<IUser> successCallback = null, Action<IServiceException> failCallback = null);
        void Logout(string sessionId, Action<IServiceResponse> successCallback = null, Action<IServiceException> failCallback = null);
    }`

`public interface IScopeAuthenticatable
    {
        void Login(string scope, Action callback = null);
        void Logout();
    }`

Plus, different services should initialize themselves in different ways:
`App42API.BuildUserService();` for App42 or `FB.Init();` for facebook.

What should I use: abstract class or interfaces in this situation in order to follow SOLID principles and have only `Authenticatable` or `IAuthenticatable` type in login page? 
How should I treat third party plugins here to adopt them to this architecture? Because I can't change their's source code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you won't change implementations of other services. Instead, you will provide **Adapters**. Each adapter will implement your interface but internally will use another implementation.

Then, in case of any differences, you can introduce an object parameter:

```
void Login( LoginParameters parameters, ... )
```

and then have

```
public class LoginPasswordParameters : LoginParameters ...

public class SmartCardParameters : LoginParameters ...
```

or even just have your LoginParameters flexible enough

```
public class LoginParameters
{
    public List<Tuple<string, string>> Parameters ...
```

so that instead of a class hierarchy, you have a class that holds key-value pairs of all possible login parameters.

When it comes to this specific activity, logging using common identity providers, you **don't have to** invent your own interfaces. This is because most providers implement the very same OAuth2 protocols and there are already implemented solutions where both abstractions and implementations are already available. Take a look at the DotnetOpenAuth library for example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm quite new to all of this. How could DotnetOpenAuth library be used alongside with Facebook SDK and App42 SDK within Unity Engine project? How do these things work together? Much appreciate your help!

Comment: It can't, you misunderstood me. DotnetOpenAuth implements Oauth2 protocol for several authentication providers, it has nothing to do with Unity.